# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in php, but works in sqlplus

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have an SQL query in an .sql file that I'm trying to execute with php, but it gives me the error mentioned in the title. However, when I paste it into sqlplus or run the file from there, everything is fine. Here is the query:

```
SELECT name,
        followers,
        friends,
        Nvl(no_of_tweets, 0) statuses,
        Nvl(mentioned, 0) mentioned,
        rts,
        Nvl(favs, 0) favs,
        ( ( 10 * followers + 5 * friends + 12 * Nvl(no_of_tweets, 0) + 15 *
                Nvl(mentioned, 0) + 14 * rts + 15 * Nvl(favs, 0) ) / 10 ) h_index
    FROM   users U
        left join (SELECT T.user_id_str,
                            Count(*)       AS no_of_tweets,
                            SUM(retweets)  rts,
                            SUM(favorites) favs,
                            mentioned
                    FROM   tweets T
                            left join (SELECT user_id_str,
                                            Count(*) AS mentioned
                                        FROM   mentions
                                        GROUP  BY user_id_str) M
                                    ON T.user_id_str = M.user_id_str
                    GROUP  BY T.user_id_str,
                                mentioned) C
                ON U.user_id_str = C.user_id_str
                ORDER BY h_index DESC;
```

What are some debugging methods that could help me find the issue or what is wrong with this command?

This is my PHP code:

```
$query = ':sql';
$st_sql = oci_parse($con, $query); 
oci_bind_by_name($st_sql, ':sql', file_get_contents($path)); 
$r = oci_execute($st_sql); 
if (!$r) { 
    $e = oci_error($st_sql);
    echo $e['message']; 
}
```

Comment: Use nick's (now deleted) answer and remove the semi-colon from the end of the query.

Comment: Ok it worked, thanks

Comment: For future readers: this is not how to use bind variables.  They should be used to substitute data into a statement because bind variables are treated as data, not statements.  Review the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) or Oracle's free [PHP book](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).